# Can't connect to ec2 instance for the first time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image: AWS console]I made the new ec2 instance with RedHat. I couldn't even connect once (I was trying to follow this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console)
Amazon console shows that instance is running, I downloaded the .pem file converted it using PuTTYgen to .ppk. The port is set to 22, connection type SSH, the key file path is in SSH auth.  I was trying those hostnames

- publicIP
- DNSname
- ec2-user@DNSname

Red color here matches the public IPv4

[image: Putty configuration]
[image: Putty configuration2]

but every single time I get PuTTY pop up

Network Error connection refused

Some of you know what am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your Putty config?? Have you tried user as root instead of ec2-user??

Comment: I think he can't even type ec2-user into the console, because the PuTTY console won't open. - Am I right?

Comment: Yes I tried with root@dns as well,all the things I changed in putty are listed in the question

Comment: Yes, the console does not even open

Comment: Does the security group of the instance allow incoming traffic on port 22?

Comment: Serucity group inbound is set to Type:SSH protocol:TCP  Port range :22

Comment: May you attach some screenshots of your setings?

Comment: I am not sure, but the red bar seems to be a bit short. Did you coppy the public IPV4? Did you already try to connect to the IPV4 without your username?

Comment: yes, I did, they seem to be short because all of them are just 2 digit numbers

Comment: would it be a problem, if you send me your ip and key and I try, if I am able to connect? The IP will change every time, you restart your machine and you can create a new key after that.

Comment: Shared a github project with you @NelDav

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204216/discussion-between-neldav-and-nav).